# What is the best way to iterate though an array and create condition logic in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

The title should explain it, but here is some more detail.

I'm creating a CMS that will allow the client to input their own content. The component I'm creating will have sections that will highlight when window center scroll position is within the section height. At render I am getting `let {top, bottom} = row.getBoundingClientRect()` of each section and storing those in an array. I'd like to then create a method that loops through the array and creates if statements that will later be checked in my `handleScroll (event)` method.

I was thinking of just creating a forEach loop on the stored `top,bottom` array and checking within the `handleScroll` method, but I'm concerned about performance.

I'm wondering what the best way to do this would be?

EDIT: Per request, this is what I have now

```
  data: () => ({
    activeItem: null,
    ...
    scrollElements: [],
    ...
  }),
  mounted () {
    ...

    let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.textSide')
    elements.forEach((row) => {
      let {top, bottom} = row.getBoundingClientRect()
      this.scrollElements.push({ top: top, bottom: bottom, })
    })
  },
  ...
  },
  methods: {
    handleScroll (event) {
      let scrollPosTop = event.path[0].scrollingElement.scrollTop
      let h = window.innerHeight;
      scrollPosTop = scrollPosTop + (h / 2)
      this.scrollElements.forEach((pos, i) => {
        if (scrollPosTop >= pos.top && scrollPosTop <= pos.bottom) {
          this.activeItem = i
        }
      })
    },
    ...
  },
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried and we can go from there.

Comment: I hardly doubt that your clients will input enough sections per page to actually matter, but if you want the performant approach you'd use an [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver)

Comment: "*creates if statements that will later be checked*" - what would the code inside these if statements actually do?